# Macbook Mail takes very long to receive mail

Tags: mail.app, email

So lately, my Macbook Pro 15" late 2014 has some bugs in the Mail app. It takes hours to receive a mail from anyone. Whereas my phone receives the mail in seconds after it being sent, the Mac takes hours to do so. The recent mail does not show up at all! The only e-mails I can see are from 5 or 6 hours ago. I don't believe the network is an issue since the phone and my laptop are on the same Wi-fi.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Could you do a speed test and post the results? How frequently is Apple Mail fetching the emails?

Comment: Download is 0.92 Mbps and Upload is 0.43 Mbps.
Shit slow I know but have had no problems in other devices with such mail stuff.
So I sent a test email from another Gmail ID to one of the IDs signed into my Mail.
It took 1 minute for it to reach my phone but took 5 minutes for the Mail app on my Macbook to show the notification.

Comment: That's terribly slow. It means the download speed is 115KB and upload is 54KB. You most likey just need to wait a long time till all the emails are synchronized. You could try to move your Mac closer to the wifi router and test the speed again to see whether the problem is the wifi or the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

In Apple Mail you can check what's going on by clicking on `Windows` -> `Activity` or pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and click on the tab General. Check what intervat you set there. You might want to set it to `Every minute`.

Comment: The interval for cecking for mail was set at automatically. Is that better or worse for the sync?